# ScrollView not working (only on android) reactnative

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

This is only happening for one of the custom components that I have created. This use to work but it randomly stopped. I have tried to move `ScrollView` in different parts of the function (before `View`, around `Card` ...) but I've had no success. The little scrollbar on the right hand side shows...you just can't scroll. But it works without any issues on iOS

I also tried to give `View` that wraps `ScrollView` `flex: 1` but no success.

I'm running `expo v42`
using `native base ^2.15.2`

The component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';


import { Card, CardItem } from 'native-base';


export default function ExerciseCard(props) {
    const { iconSource, iconType, customStyle, SVG } = props;
    return (

        <Card style={styles.Card}> // this is from native base

            <CardItem style={[styles.ExerciseCard, customStyle]}> // also native base
               //icon stuff
              // dynamic svg
                <View style={styles.TopToBottom}>
                  <ScrollView>
                        {props.children} // this can have bunch of text hence why I need to scroll through them
                  </ScrollView>
                </View>

            </CardItem>
        </Card >
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can bring you a solution but I've already encountered this kind of issue, and I had to wrap the content in a touch component like touchableOpacity.

I think the issue depends on the layering / wrapping around the scrollview.